# How to create multiple non-shared instances without injecting the ServiceLocator in ZendFramework2?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, factory, service-locator

I have a factory that creates a non-shared service and a controller factory in my module.config.php file. This part of the configuration looks like this:

```
"service_manager" => [
    "factories" => [
        Entity\User::class => Factory\Entity\UserFactory::class
    ],
    "shared" => [
        Entity\User::class => false
    ]
],
"controllers" => [
    "factories" => [
        Controller\UserAdminController::class => Factory\Controller\UserAdminControllerFactory::class
    ]
]
```

The User entity is non-shared, because I allow the administrator to add multiple users at the same time, therefore I need to instantiate multiple instances of the User entity class.

Here is my controller factory:

```
<?php

namespace User\Factory\Controller\Core;

use User\Controller\UserAdminController;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use User\Entity\User;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class UserAdminControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface{

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param array|null $options
     *
     * @return UserAdminController
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null){
        $serviceLocator = $container->getServiceLocator();

        return new UserAdminController($serviceLocator->get(User::class));
    }

    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return UserAdminController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator){
        return $this($serviceLocator, UserAdminController::class);
    }

}
```

Currently, it injects only a single instance of the User entity class inside the constructor of the controller. However, I need an undefined amount of new instances, based on what the administrator wants to do.

One possible solution is to pass the whole service locator and create new instances every time by calling `$this->getServiceLocator()->get(User::class)` in the controller, BUT this is considered to be an anti-pattern.

The question here is how to create new instances of the User in the controller, using the UserFactory class?

**EDIT1: Add UserFactory:**

```
<?php

namespace User\Factory\Entity\Core;

use User\Entity\User;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class UserFactory implements FactoryInterface{

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param array|null $options
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null){
        $urlHelper = $container->get("ViewHelperManager")->get("url");

        return new User($urlHelper);
    }

    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator){
        return $this($serviceLocator, User::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe here what you are looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447442/dependency-injection-in-factories?rq=1
i'm not sure, but why not inject the factory into controller and create user entities

Comment: Can you also share the contents of UserFactory? Do you have a strong reason to write a factory for your domain entities? Anyway, I would try to write a controller plugin for such task.

Comment: @Roman Because I need the service locator in my factory, and if I inject the factory, I will have to inject the service locator as well, which is an anti-pattern. Therefore, I cannot do this. Any ideas?

Comment: @edigu I don't think creating a controller plugin is a good idea, because it induces more dependencies into the controller and to be more specific - in EVERY contoller, because controller plugins are available application-wide. I will add the UserFactory, but that applies to every obejct that has dependecies. For example a form, or a fieldset that has to be repeated multiple times (to have multiple instances), which queries the database.

Comment: @edigu I have added the UserFactory, you can take a look.

Comment: You could use clone of a User object every time you need a new copy.

Comment: @akond As far as i can understand, your idea is to inject the User entity into the controller and call `$newUser = clone $this->user;` every time I need a new instance, thus keeping the `$this->user` instance clean and untouched. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes, precisely so.

Comment: I want to answer my own question and I'm going to write this as an answer. Is this a common approach? I mean, is it considered a good practice?

Comment: Sure, why not? Go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to inject a new instance of the User entity into the controller. The controller factory should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace User\Factory\Controller\Core;

use User\Controller\UserAdminController;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use User\Entity\User;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class UserAdminControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface{

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param array|null $options
     *
     * @return UserAdminController
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null){
        $serviceLocator = $container->getServiceLocator();

        return new UserAdminController($serviceLocator->get(User::class));
    }

    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return UserAdminController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator){
        return $this($serviceLocator, UserAdminController::class);
    }

}
```

Inside the controller, when a new instance of user is needed, it can be simply created by calling PHP's clone function. Here is an example action in the controller of how to do it:

```
<?php

namespace User\Controller\Core;

use User\Entity\User;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class UserAdminController extends AbstractActionController {

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(User $user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    /**
     * @return ViewModel
     */
    public function indexAction(){
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            $usersData = $this->params()->fromPost("usersData");
            foreach($usersData as $userData){
                $newUser = clone $this->user;
                $newUser->fromArray($userData);
                $newUser->save();
            }
        }

        return ViewModel();
    }

}
```

Injecting the UserFactory into the controller is **NOT** an option, because the factory uses the service locator to create new instances of the User class. If the factory is being injected to the controller, the service locator should be injected, too, BUT this is considered an anti-pattern and moreover, it is deprecated and considered a bad practice in ZendFramework3.